# Sass support in DevTools mysteriously not present?

Tags: css, google-chrome, sass, google-chrome-devtools, source-maps

I've spent some time trying to set up source-mapping between Chrome and my .scss files so that I can edit and save within the browser for general debugging purposes. One of the more important steps to this, though, seems to be enabling the DevTools experiments, and then selecting "Support for Sass." Well, I have enabled the experiments several times, and still there is no box for Sass support. Has Chrome possibly included it automatically in a newer update?

Screen shot for proof of its non-existence. (Never mind, I'm not allowed to post it).

Comment: hope it helps http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/developing-with-sass-and-chrome-devtools/

Answer (score 0):

Your Chrome might have an update error. If you click the menu, and click About Google Chrome, you'll see your version (should be 31+). Mine showed an old version and an update error. 

 
Uninstall Chrome, restart the computer, install chrome again. 

 
You should have all the latest tools. SASS support was no longer experimental on my version, and turned on by default for me. But you might have to: 
 
- Go the URL chrome://flags then Enable Developer Tools experiments.
- Open DevTools (Right click a web page Inspect Element)
- Click the cog icon in the bottom right
- Click Experiments, and click Enable SASS Support
- Click General, and click Enable CSS source maps